# mysql joins where unique row required

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables : products and product_images.

**products:**

```
product_id      price     discount    product_name
---------------------------------------------------
1               10.00      1.0        product 1
2               20         1.0        product 2
```

**product_images:**

```
product_id    images
--------------------------
1             image 1
1             image 2
1             image 3
2             image 1
```

etc....

I need to select each product_id, price,discount,product_name and **only the first image from Product_images**. Joins are producing the same product_id repeated with multiple images..

How can i write a query for the same so that product_id is unique with only first image from product_images table ???

Comment: Is there any field on product_images that identify the order of that image besides the name of it ?

Comment: @Jorge Campos The product_images table has following structure, id (auto-increment), product_id,images with product_images.product_id linked to products.product_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that :

```
  select p.`product_id`, `price`, `discount`, `product_name`,`images`
  from products p 
  inner join product_images pi On p.`product_id` = pi.`product_id`
  Where stock_status = 'stock' AND status = 'Enabled'
  group by p.`product_id`
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0430/2)

Comment: Thank you very..very much...That did it...One more question..is how can I add a WHERE clause to the above query where I have 2 fields stock_status and status in products table....Where stock_status = 'stock' AND status = 'Enabled'

Comment: Where stock_status = 'stock' AND status = 'Enabled' is returning no rows ??  Sorry, I made a typo....Thank you very much

Comment: its your condition , you must be sure if there is rows with those conditions ,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with an aggregate query that takes the "first" image.

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.price, a.discount, a.product_name, MIN(b.image) AS image
  FROM products AS a
  LEFT JOIN product_images AS b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
 GROUP BY a.product_id, a.price, a.discount, a.product_name
```

The trick here is that the aggregate `MIN()` function will find the "first" image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT p.*,GROUP_CONTACT( pi.images )
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON pi.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

This will give you a comma-separated list of all the images for the product. The problem I see here is you don't seem to currently have a way of defining the "first" image for a product. Maybe you need to add an order column to your product_images table?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the comments, here is the query you need:

```
select product_id, price, discount, product_name, image
  from
     (select p.product_id, 
             p.price, 
             p.discount, 
             p.product_name,
             min(pi.id) im_id
        from products p 
               inner join products_image pi 
               on (p.product_id=pi.product_id) 
       group by p.product_id, 
             p.price, 
             p.discount, 
             p.product_name ) pd 
           inner join
         products_image pimg on ( pd.im_id = pimg.id )
```